# How to randomly select fewer numbers in a list in python and make it unique each time

Tags: python, list

My topic phrase might not be so good, i'm bad with titles.
Let's say i have

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and i want to randomly make a new shorter list with different numbers in it.
like

```
x_new = [2,4,6,8]
```

I tried coding like this

```
B = 10
import random
for r in range(B):
    x[r] = random.randint(0,9)
print(x)
```

I got a randomized result but it was way different from what i wanted. It picked same numbers like `[3, 3, 4, ...]`

Also the new list has same length with the old list. I want it to randomly have different lengths.

Answer (score 2):

you can try [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
import random
x=random.sample(range(1,9), random.randint(1,8))
print(x)
```

output:

```
[2, 5, 7]
[7, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 8]
[4, 1, 8, 6, 7]
...
```

Comment: Note that `range(1,9)` excludes `9`, which is not what OP wants. Use `range(1, 10)` instead.

Comment: Yeah, i want something like that. But after putting down

Comment: random.sample(range(1,9), random.randint(1,9)).  Will i write print(x) before it displays that result

Comment: or what willl be in print()